# Error when sending from TrajClient

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, joint-trajectory-action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to control my robot arm and send it commands realized through a simple trajectory client and a trajectory execution server. I have my client connected to the server but as soon as I send a command I get this error:

```
right_joint_trajectory_action: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback_<std::allocator<void> >]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[right_joint_trajectory_action-16] process has died [pid 15955, exit code -6, cmd /root/ros_workspace/DrRobotH20/drrobot_jaguar4x4_player/bin/right_joint_trajectory_action __name:=right_joint_trajectory_action __log:=/root/.ros/log/b718d428-70ac-11e2-859d-d067e5ea9c5a/right_joint_trajectory_action-16.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/b718d428-70ac-11e2-859d-d067e5ea9c5a/right_joint_trajectory_action-16*.log
```

Interestingly enough, when I use the warehouse planner with my real robot data, as soon as I try to "execute on robot" I get the same error! I believe there is a small bug in my code but I can't find it.

Below I have posted the joint_trajectory_action server code (for my robot's right arm) and the action client code:

**ACTION SERVER:**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <actionlib/server/action_server.h>

#include <trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h>
#include <control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction.h>
#include <control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback.h>

const double DEFAULT_GOAL_THRESHOLD = 0.01;

class JointTrajectoryExecuter
{
private:
  typedef actionlib::ActionServer<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> JTAS;
  typedef JTAS::GoalHandle GoalHandle;
public:
  JointTrajectoryExecuter(ros::NodeHandle &n) :
    node_(n),
    action_server_(node_, "r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action",
                   boost::bind(&JointTrajectoryExecuter::goalCB, this, _1),
                   boost::bind(&JointTrajectoryExecuter::cancelCB, this, _1),
                   false),
    has_active_goal_(false)
  {
    using namespace XmlRpc;
    ros::NodeHandle pn("~");
    
    joint_names_.push_back("base_to_right_shoulder");
    joint_names_.push_back("right_rotator_to_tricep");
    joint_names_.push_back("right_upper_to_lower_bicep");
    joint_names_.push_back("right_lower_bicep_to_upper_forearm");
    joint_names_.push_back("right_lower_forearm_to_wrist");
    joint_names_.push_back("right_wrist_to_hand");




    pn.param("constraints/goal_time", goal_time_constraint_, 0.0);

    // Gets the constraints for each joint.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < joint_names_.size(); ++i)
    {
      std::string ns = std::string("constraints/") + joint_names_[i];
      double g, t;
      pn.param(ns + "/goal", g, DEFAULT_GOAL_THRESHOLD);
      pn.param(ns + "/trajectory", t, -1.0);
      goal_constraints_[joint_names_[i]] = g;
      trajectory_constraints_[joint_names_[i]] = t;
    }
    pn.param("constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance", stopped_velocity_tolerance_, 0.01);


    pub_controller_command_ =
      node_.advertise<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory>("command", 1);
    sub_controller_state_ =
      node_.subscribe("feedback_states", 1, &JointTrajectoryExecuter::controllerStateCB, this);
    
    action_server_.start();
  }

  ~JointTrajectoryExecuter()
  {
   pub_controller_command_.shutdown();
    sub_controller_state_.shutdown();
    watchdog_timer_.stop();
  }

  bool withinGoalConstraints(const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedbackConstPtr &msg,
                             const std::map<std::string, double>& constraints,
                             const trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory& traj) {
    ROS_DEBUG("Checking goal contraints");
    int last = traj.points.size() - 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < msg->joint_names.size(); ++i)
    {
      double abs_error = fabs(msg->actual.positions[i]-traj.points[last].positions[i]);
      double goal_constraint = constraints.at(msg->joint_names[i]);
      if (goal_constraint >= 0 && abs_error > goal_constraint)
      {
    ROS_DEBUG("Bad constraint: %f, abs_errs: %f", goal_constraint, abs_error);
        return false;
      }
      ROS_DEBUG("Checking constraint: %f, abs_errs: %f", goal_constraint, abs_error);
    }
    return true;
  }

private:

  static bool setsEqual(const std::vector<std::string> &a, const std::vector<std::string> &b)
  {
    if (a.size() != b.size())
      return false;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (count(b.begin(), b.end(), a[i]) != 1)
        return false;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (count(a.begin(), a.end(), b[i]) != 1)
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  void watchdog(const ros::TimerEvent &e)
  {
    ros::Time now = ros::Time::now();

    // Aborts the active goal if the controller does not appear to be active.
    if (has_active_goal_)
    {
      bool should_abort = false;
      if (!last_controller_state_)
      {
        should_abort = true;
        ROS_WARN("Aborting goal because we have never heard a controller state message.");
      }
      else if ((now - last_controller_state_->header.stamp) > ros::Duration(5.0))
      {
        should_abort = true;
        ROS_WARN("Aborting goal because we haven't heard from the controller in %.3lf seconds",
                 (now - last_controller_state_->header.stamp).toSec());
      }

      if (should_abort)
      {
        // Stops the controller.
        trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory empty;
        empty.joint_names = joint_names_;
        pub_controller_command_.publish(empty);

        // Marks the current goal as aborted.
        active_goal_.setAborted();
        has_active_goal_ = false;
      }
    }
  }

  void goalCB(GoalHandle gh)
  {
    // Ensures that the joints in the goal match the joints we are commanding.
    ROS_DEBUG("Received goal: goalCB");
    if (!setsEqual(joint_names_, gh.getGoal()->trajectory.joint_names))
    {
      ROS_ERROR("Joints on incoming goal don't match our joints");
      gh.setRejected();
      return;
    }

    // Cancels the currently active goal.
    if (has_active_goal_)
    {
      ROS_DEBUG("Received new goal, canceling current goal");
      // Stops the controller.
      trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory empty;
      empty.joint_names = joint_names_;
      pub_controller_command_.publish(empty);

      // Marks the current goal as canceled.
      active_goal_.setCanceled();
      has_active_goal_ = false;
    }

    // Sends the trajectory along to the controller
    if(withinGoalConstraints(last_controller_state_,
                             goal_constraints_,
                             gh.getGoal()->trajectory)) {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("Already within goal constraints");
      gh.setAccepted();
      gh.setSucceeded();
    } else {
      gh.setAccepted();
      active_goal_ = gh;
      has_active_goal_ = true;

      ROS_INFO("Publishing trajectory");

      current_traj_ = active_goal_.getGoal()->trajectory;
      pub_controller_command_.publish(current_traj_);
    }
  }

  void cancelCB(GoalHandle gh)
  {
    ROS_DEBUG("Received action cancel request");
    if (active_goal_ == gh)
    {
      // Stops the controller.
      trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory empty;
      empty.joint_names = joint_names_;
      pub_controller_command_.publish(empty);

      // Marks the current goal as canceled.
      active_goal_.setCanceled();
      has_active_goal_ = false;
    }
  }


  ros::NodeHandle node_;
  JTAS action_server_;
  ros::Publisher pub_controller_command_;
  ros::Subscriber sub_controller_state_;
  ros::Timer watchdog_timer_;

  bool has_active_goal_;
  GoalHandle active_goal_;
  trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory current_traj_;


  std::vector<std::string> joint_names_;
  std::map<std::string,double> goal_constraints_;
  std::map<std::string,double> trajectory_constraints_;
  double goal_time_constraint_;
  double stopped_velocity_tolerance_;

  control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedbackConstPtr last_controller_state_;

  void controllerStateCB(const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryFeedbackConstPtr &msg)
  {
    //ROS_DEBUG("Checking controller state feedback");
    last_controller_state_ = msg;
    ros::Time now = ros::Time::now();

    if (!has_active_goal_)
    {
      //ROS_DEBUG("No active goal, ignoring feedback");
      return;
    }
    if (current_traj_.points.empty())
    {
      ROS_DEBUG("Current trajecotry is empty, ignoring feedback");
      return;
    }
    /* NOT CONCERNED ABOUT TRAJECTORY TIMING AT THIS POINT
    if (now < current_traj_.header.stamp + current_traj_.points[0].time_from_start)
      return;
    */

    if (!setsEqual(joint_names_, msg->joint_names))
    {
      ROS_ERROR("Joint names from the controller don't match our joint names.");
      return;
    }

    // Checking for goal constraints
    // Checks that we have ended inside the goal constraints

    ROS_DEBUG("Checking goal contraints");
    if(withinGoalConstraints(msg, 
                             goal_constraints_,
                             current_traj_)) {
      ROS_INFO("Inside goal contraints, return success for action");
      active_goal_.setSucceeded();
      has_active_goal_ = false;
    }
  }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "right_joint_trajectory_action_node");
  ros::NodeHandle node;//("~");
  JointTrajectoryExecuter jte(node);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

**ACTION CLIENT**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient< control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction > TrajClient;

class RobotArm
{
private:
  // Action client for the joint trajectory action 
  // used to trigger the arm movement action
  TrajClient* traj_client_;

public:
  //! Initialize the action client and wait for action server to come up
  RobotArm() 
  {
    // tell the action client that we want to spin a thread by default
    traj_client_ = new TrajClient("r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action", true);

    // wait for action server to come up
    while(!traj_client_->waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0))){
      ROS_INFO("Waiting for the joint_trajectory_action server");
    }
  }

  //! Clean up the action client
  ~RobotArm()
  {
    delete traj_client_;
  }

  //! Sends the command to start a given trajectory
  void startTrajectory(control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal goal)
  {
    // When to start the trajectory: 1s from now
    goal.trajectory.header.stamp = ros::Time::now() + ros::Duration(1.0);
    traj_client_->sendGoal(goal);
  }

  //! Generates a simple trajectory with two waypoints, used as an example
  /*! Note that this trajectory contains two waypoints, joined together
      as a single trajectory. Alternatively, each of these waypoints could
      be in its own trajectory - a trajectory can have one or more waypoints
      depending on the desired application.
  */
  control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal armExtensionTrajectory()
  {
    //our goal variable
    control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal goal;

    // First, the joint names, which apply to all waypoints
    goal.trajectory.joint_names.push_back("base_to_right_shoulder");
    goal.trajectory.joint_names.push_back("right_rotator_to_tricep");
    goal.trajectory.joint_names.push_back("right_upper_to_lower_bicep");
    goal.trajectory.joint_names.push_back("right_lower_bicep_to_upper_forearm");
    goal.trajectory.joint_names.push_back("right_lower_forearm_to_wrist");
    goal.trajectory.joint_names.push_back("right_wrist_to_hand");



    // We will have two waypoints in this goal trajectory
    goal.trajectory.points.resize(2);

    // First trajectory point
    // Positions
    int ind = 0;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions.resize(6);
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[0] = 0.0;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[1] = 0.0;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[2] = 0.0;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[3] = 0.0;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[4] = 0.0;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[5] = 0.0;
    // Velocities
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].velocities.resize(6);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
    {
      goal.trajectory.points[ind].velocities[j] = 0.0;
    }
    // To be reached 1 second after starting along the trajectory
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].time_from_start = ros::Duration(1.0);

    // Second trajectory point
    // Positions
    ind += 1;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions.resize(6);
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[0] = -0.3;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[1] = 0.2;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[2] = -0.1;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[3] = -1.2;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[4] = 1.5;
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].positions[5] = -0.3;
    // Velocities
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].velocities.resize(6);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
    {
      goal.trajectory.points[ind].velocities[j] = 0.0;
    }
    // To be reached 2 seconds after starting along the trajectory
    goal.trajectory.points[ind].time_from_start = ros::Duration(2.0);

    //we are done; return the goal
    return goal;
  }

  //! Returns the current state of the action
  actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState getState()
  {
    return traj_client_->getState();
  }
 
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Init the ROS node
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_driver");

  RobotArm arm;
  // Start the trajectory
  arm.startTrajectory(arm.armExtensionTrajectory());
  // Wait for trajectory completion
  while(!arm.getState().isDone() && ros::ok())
  {
    usleep(50000);
  }
}
```

So when I run my program, I can launch the server fine and look at the /r_arm_controller topics and watch its status. But when I play the simple_trajectory client everything crashes with that error above.

Any help with this is hugely appreciated!

Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54510/error-when-sending-from-trajclient/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-02-09**:
Hi Martin, this kind of bug is much easier to find with a debugger such as gdb. Could you upload a .tar archive of your whole package somewhere? Alternatively, run the server in gdb and have a look at the backtrace; this should tell you the line number of the error.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-02-09**:
BTW, you shouldn't be running this as root. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Martin, I figured out the error! It was from not publishing the FollowJointTrajectoryFeedback feeback state :) And why shouldn't I be running on as root? It was how the other guy working in the lab had it, I like not needing to type sudo all the time haha

---

Originally posted by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) with karma: 464 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0